# Difficult to run pytest with a fastAPI and ODM beanie, I get the error: beanie.exceptions.CollectionWasNotInitialized

Tags: mongodb, pytest, fastapi, beanie

Whenever I execute pytest with this code, I consistently encounter the error: **FAILED tests/test_main.py::test_create_todo - beanie.exceptions.CollectionWasNotInitialized**. Do you have any insights on how to initialize the database before running the test?

```
# tests/test_main.py
import pytest
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from src.core.database import init_db
from src.main import app

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
async def initialize_test_database():
    # Initialize test database before running any tests
    yield await init_db("mongodb://root:example@localhost:27017", "test_todoapp")  # Assuming you have a separate test database

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    return TestClient(app)

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_create_todo(client):
    data = {"title": "Todo 1", "description": "Description Todo 1"}
    response = await client.post("/todos", json=data)
    assert response.status_code == 201
```

and my database.py:

```
import os
from beanie import init_beanie
import motor.motor_asyncio

from src.models.todo import Todo


async def init_db(mongo_uri: str, database_name: str):
    client = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient(mongo_uri)
    await init_beanie(database=client[database_name], document_models=[Todo])


def get_mongo_uri():
    return os.environ.get("MONGO_URI", "mongodb://root:example@localhost:27017")

def get_mongo_db_name():
    return os.environ.get("MONGO_DB_NAME", "todoapp")

async def initialize_database():
    await init_db(get_mongo_uri(), get_mongo_db_name())
```

and my main.py:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from src.core.config import settings
from src.core.database import initialize_database
from src.routes.todo_routes import router as todo_router
import os

def init_router(app: FastAPI):
    app.include_router(todo_router, tags=["Todo"], prefix="/todos")

async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    await initialize_database()
    yield

def create_app() -> FastAPI:
    _app = FastAPI(
        title=settings.PROJECT_NAME,
        version=settings.PROJECT_VERSION,
        lifespan=lifespan
    )
    init_router(_app)
    return _app

app = create_app()
```

Do you have any insights on how to initialize the database before running the test?

Comment: Does initialize_test_database have to be async?

Comment: In the documentation is async: https://beanie-odm.dev/tutorial/initialization/

Comment: I'm not an expert in beanie, but I guess that the problem is that the setup fixture is async and it is does not get resolved by the moment tests start. I suggest that you make the initialize_test_database a regular function without async/await.

Comment: I found that was the rigth syntax:
def test_create_todo(client):
    with TestClient(app) as client:
        data = {"title": "Todo 1", "description": "Description Todo 1"}
        response = client.post("/todos", json=data)
        assert response.status_code == 201

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
def test_create_todo(client):
    with TestClient(app) as client:
        data = {"title": "Todo 1", "description": "Description Todo 1"}
        response = client.post("/todos", json=data)
        assert response.status_code == 201
```